# How to update whole range of date with another range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a table name shiftsDates which have following column

```
**ShiftDateID**  **ShiftID** **ShiftDate** **IsNonShiftDate**
 1                 20          3/2/2012       false
 2                 20          3/3/2012       false
 3                 20          3/4/2012       true
```

I want to update ShiftDate and IsNonShiftDate column if user select another shift date range for shift '20'. From UI I have only ShiftID value. kindly give any hint how i accomplish this task. thanks

Comment: Please add more detail. What kind of values are you working with? Do you have a ShiftID and they pick a different date range that you need the table to reflect? What do you use to determine what IsNonShiftDate should be? This question would be much easier to answer if you gave us the information you wanted to send to the database, and what you wanted the result of sending it to be.

Comment: exactly jeremy,basically  the scenerio is that the shift date are not limited to 3 rows user can expand or shrink the shiftdate range for shift 20, and isnonshift date reflect the weekenddays and any day when shift is off,and false if its a working day,im confuse that wheater to update the existing range or delet all records of shift 20 and reenter the record for shift 20. what approach should be use for this kind of task please guide me in this regard im really tied up in this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question 100% :) But I give it a try.
You have a a ShiftDateId e..g 2. and want to update all 3 rows.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET ShiftDate = <YourDate>
  , IsNonSiftDate = <true|false>
WHERE ShiftId = (SELECT ShiftId FROM YourTable WHERE ShiftDateId = <<ourId>)
```

But try to answer give me more questions?
- Column InNonShiftDate is related to work days, so you have to find out WeekDay() of the Date?
- If you get a range (start / end ) then you want to insert a row for each day in that range?
  This would be a stored procedure with a CURSOR then...

So I guess give us more Infos about your environment to give you a better answer.

Comment: In the question he said he only had the `ShiftID`, so you shouldn't need to do your filtering like that. Just saying WHERE ShiftId = @ShiftId should be sufficient.

Comment: basically  the scenerio is that the shift date are not limited to 3 rows user can expand or shrink the shiftdate range for shift 20, im confuse that wheater to update the existing range or delet all records of shift 20 and reenter the record for shift 20. what approach should be use for this kind of task please guide me in this regard im really tied up in this, thanks